# GDB pipe input to debugged file without using a file

Tags: debugging, gdb, pipe

I'm trying to pass the debugged program the output of python scrip like this:

```
(gdb) run $(python -c "print('A'*60)")
```

However this is passed as argument.

```
(gdb) run < $(python -c "print('A'*60)")
```

This reports an error as it replaces the right part withs the 'A's and fails to open a file with such name.

I'm looking for sort of piping mechanism in gdb.

```
python -c "print('A'*60)" > input.txt
(gdb) run < input.txt
```

Would be a solution but I don't have the permission to create a file (I'm trying to solve a stack-smashing based CTF)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
(gdb) run <(python -c "print('A'*60)")
```

(This is a shell redirection feature, not GDB redirection feature).

> I don't have the permission to create a file

It's rare for the system to not allow you to create files in `/tmp`.

```
python -c "print('A'*60)" > /tmp/input.txt
(gdb) run < /tmp/input.txt
```

Comment: "/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"
the first option dosn't seem to work.

Comment: it's actually 
`(gdb) run < <(python -c "print('A'*60)")`